# Omnibox multipe Keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

My question is about the Omnibox. The think provided by the Chrome API, i wanted to know if there is a possibility to have a multiple keyword on the manifest.

I've thinking about a regex or something like that but i don't really know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've just find a solution.

I've discover that when you make a search for 'TRY' by using google the url is :

> http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=fr&site=&source=hp&q=TRY&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ec3d6f66084ab746

And when it come from Chrome URL it's :

> http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=TRY

So basically if i check if there is sourceid=Chrome on the url i can redirect like this. What do you think ?

```
// If Google Search from the URL (sourceid)
if(URL.match('google') && parseUri(URL).queryKey['sourceid'] == 'chrome')
{
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=' + parseUri(URL).queryKey['q'] });
    return;
} // If Bing Search from the URL (setmkt)
else if(URL.match('bing') && parseUri(URL).queryKey['setmkt'])
{
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=' + parseUri(URL).queryKey['p'] });
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I used as well (forgot to mention it). Just something to keep in mind is that it won't be sending this parameter if you manually change search provider (to localized version of google in your country for example)

Comment: Yeah, in fact i think it's the best solution, the problem is just that i have to write it for all type of search engine... So not really generic but well...

You see another solution ?

Comment: Nope, can't think about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not possible.

I see you are still trying to make custom search provider. I wanted to give you an idea of what I did in a similar extension which triggers google lucky search instead of regular one if you type your keyword in capital letters for example. It has some pitfalls and limitations (the biggest one is that default search provider must be google and it still briefly shows google search results), but at least something:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
              var url = $.url.setUrl(tab.url);
               if((url.attr("protocol") == "https" && url.attr("host").indexOf("encrypted.google.") == 0
                                      || url.attr("protocol") == "http" && url.attr("host").indexOf("www.google.") == 0)
                              && url.attr("path") == "/search" && url.param("q") && isAllCapital(url.param("q"))) {

                      //do something with search term inside url.param("q")
              }
      }
});
```

(I am using [URL Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) plugin).

Comment: Thanks to help me again dude. The thing is that i've allready thinked about this solution, but i have to use yahoo search. Technically what i can do is to redirect all user in yahoo, but well it's to much...

I really keep searching for another solution, but not a lot of infos on the web about this...