# How to make Chrome auto choose the search engine based on a pattern in the typed text?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Use case: user types something like:

- <kbd>AA1234↵</kbd> - i want the browser to directly go to http://example.com/search/%s
- <kbd>ZZ666↵</kbd> - i want the browser to directly go to http://acme.com/search/%s
- fallback not normal search for non matching patterns

I'm sure that this cannot be just configured, so it would require probably to write an extension (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this example: [omnibox-multipe-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354426/omnibox-multipe-keyword)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "description": "Parse XXX-000 pattern from entered url for google search and redirect to Jira",
  "name": "Jira Search",
  "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
  "version": "1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "9",

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
function navigate(url) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url});
  });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
        if(/google\.com.+search\?q.\w+\-\d+/.test(tab.url)) {
            var ticket =  /\w+\-\d+/.exec(tab.url)
            navigate("http://jira..../QuickSearch.jspa?searchString="
                + ticket[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

this simple check \w+-\d+/ regexp in google search and if found - redirect to jira search...

Comment: Yes, it works but I had to hack it, because my default search was `google.co.uk`? Do you know a variant that doesn't depend on current search engine?

Comment: haven't found :(
will be cool to have some pre processing before search - to choose search engine or to take some actions

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is use the [Omnibox API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html). You will have to define a keyword (`xyz`) and when a user enteres <kbd>xyz</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>search query</kbd> your extension will get `search query` and can decide what page to open.